# Tree.js Two different scenes, two different webglrenderers may be possible or not

Tags: three.js

May people has asked in the past for two or more different viewports for the same scene.
This is not my goal.

I have **two different scenes** and I have **two different renderers**, two different div container elements and I'm sure I create two independent renderers but....
I have the similar console errors about the context , the program.... when I'm going to render the second scene.

> WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: object not from this context
>   three.js:23903 WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: uniformMatrix4fv: location is
>   not from current program three.js:23919 WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION:
>   uniform3f: location not for current program three.js:24389 WebGL:
>   INVALID_OPERATION: uniform1f: location not for current program
>   three.js:24373 WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: uniformMatrix4fv: location is
>   not fr ...

Is not it possible to do what I want? Thanks

Comment: It is possible, already did this myself (r63) Maybe you can provide some code?

Comment: Ok. Then I'll have a hidden mistake. Now I know somebody had done it. All the forum-messages and tutorials talk about 1 scene and more than one vieports. Thanks.